# Python Pillow How to take a screenshot of the screen or turn text into an image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Good day.

In my job i have to sometimes use a script to get some information out of a number or ID. Like the example bellow:

Script that i use:

```
$sh script.sh 9999999999999 abc
```

Information that appears in the screen:

```
number: 9999999999999

SQL*Plus: Release 1.2.3.4 Production on Wed Jan 10 12:35:22 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database Enterprise Edition Release 1.2.3.4 - 32bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options


NUMBER||','||SERVICE||','||CONTRACT_DATE||','||COMFIRMATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9999999999999,SERVICE_NAME_1,01-OCT-13 10.44.30 AM,Y
9999999999999,SERVICE_NAME_2,08-DEZ-14 09.52.57 AM,N
9999999999999,SERVICE_NAME_3,26-FEB-16 11.42.30 AM,Y

Disconnected from Oracle Database Enterprise Edition Release 1.2.3.4 - 32bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

I want to know how to turn whatever the script returns to me into an image, like in taking a screenshot of my terminal.

Comment: What would be the point of converting this plain text into an image?  Just select the text in your terminal, and paste it into a text editor.  Perhaps select a monospaced font so that columnar data still lines up.  (I'm not sure if PIL/Pillow can take a screenshot, but you'd have no way to know what the pixel coordinates are of the text in your terminal anyway.)

Comment: Could you try to frame your question in a more precise manner? Statements in last paragraph contradicts with your question in 1st paragraph. Also, be clear with what is the technical issue you are encountering.

Comment: @jasonharper the point would be to take a screenshot of the information to use in some forms we do here in the company.

Comment: @SunBear the last lines were updated.

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man Your question appeared to have been asked before by a Ubuntu user. http://askubuntu.com/questions/194427/what-is-the-terminal-command-to-take-a-screenshot. If you google "command line screenshot linux", you can find many similar discussions. I am assuming you are a linux user. But I think the same would be true for the other OS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be a great time to turn to the Python Package Index, PyPI. It offers modules for many things, including taking screenshots from Python.

Consider, e.g. [pyscreenshot](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyscreenshot).

Install with `pip` or your local platform-specific installer, then:

```
import pyscreenshot
im = pyscreenshot.grab()
im.save('ss.png')
```

`im` is a PIL/Pillow compatible image, easily manipulated or saved to a file.