# why python takes more time while saving the image second time?

Tags: python, performance, appium, screenshot

I want to save a png image on the hard disk. The first time it takes 1.6 seconds while the second time onwards it takes more than 3 seconds why is that?

```
import appium.webdriver
from appium import webdriver
import time
import PIL
from PIL import Image
import datetime

"""
Desired Capabilities
"""

desired_cap = {
  "deviceName": "ZY2244B53V",
  "platformName": "Android",
  "appPackage": "==",
  "appActivity": "com.tictok.tictokgame.activities.HomeActivity",
  "automationName": "UiAutomator1"
}
webdriver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub",desired_cap)
n=0
while n<2:
  a=datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
  print("time of start saving image" + str(a))
  webdriver.save_screenshot("D:/Python/winzo_memory/a.png")
  b=datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
  print("time of end saving image" + str(b))

  a=datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
  print("time of start opening image" + str(a))
  im = Image.open("a.png")
  b=datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
  print("time of end opening image" + str(b))
  n=n+1
```

output:

```
time of start saving image2020-08-23 06:56:41.252
time of end saving image2020-08-23 06:56:42.837
time of start saving image2020-08-23 06:56:42.904
time of end saving image2020-08-23 06:56:45.952
```

I am trying to take a screenshot in appium driver. Is there a faster way to take a screenshot and let python read the pixels? Thanks in advance.

My operating system is windows 7. the image is 1080X1920. and the size of the image is aprx 1.5 mb. not sure about HDD or SSD.

Comment: With that code, you don't know whether `webdriver.save_screenshot()` is slower than before or whether `Image.open()` is slower. If you put a timestamp between those two, you can probably eliminate one of them.

Comment: I changed that, it seems the saving the image takes 3 seconds on 2nd attempt onwards.

Comment: My guess it's overwritting an existing inage (that's also opened), if you change the name you save to, does it still happen?

Comment: need to check that. will update in few mins

Comment: with chnaged names also it takes 3 seconds

Comment: How do i take continuous screenshots and read them in real time?

Comment: How big is the image size (in Mo)? What is its resolution (width and height)? Do you have an HDD or an SSD? What is your operating system? (Please put those information in the question directly).

Comment: Ok, now that we have a few new observations, you should update the question accordingly. It's not reading the image, it's saving the image that takes longer. Also, I think you don't need 6 of the 9 imports. Always try to reduce the code as much as possible. It makes it easier for us to set up the environment and reproduce the problem. Probably you can also remove the lines `a=... b=... c=... if a== b== c==` without affecting the issue. Just make a copy of your project and simplify it for Stack Overflow. That's a good practice.

Comment: Ok, great. Thanks for keeping up, answering comments and updating the question. You got my +1 now. I hope someone can help you. I'm not in mobile app development

Comment: I can't find my way around the appium docs and I don't use it myself. I guess there must be a `get_screenshot_as_png()` type of function rather than `save_screenshot()`. If so, you get that and use PIL `Image.open(BytesIO(THAT_THING))` If you can pass a link to the current API docs, that might help.

Comment: Yes i tried to get screenshot as png. But it takes same time as above method. I was wondering how game bots are made, while continuously taking screenshots.

Comment: A small image like this should be saved in a fraction of a second. I don't know how this package succeed to be so slow. What about using another package? [pyscreenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41748280) takes 200 ms on my machine to save a screenshot to the disk (140 ms to grab it). It also support in-memory saving (regarding the doc).

Comment: Will it work on appium as well?

Comment: pyscreenshot works on taking the screenshot of computer screen and not the appium

Comment: Do u have any other alternative?

Comment: Is your disk nearly full?

Comment: I have around 7 gb in c drive

Comment: May be it's because i am taking screenshot with appium driver. Does anyone know how to take screenshot faster with appium driver.